# How efficient is Django Core Pagination?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a query set of some 500 objects... which I get after running the initial query set in some loops and checking a few conditions and excluding the objects that do not meet the criteria... and I am displaying these objects using Django core pagination.. how efficient is this and if not, what are the alternatives.

EDIT: this code probably does not make sense. but this is how I am filtering the initial query set

```
projs = Model.objects.filter(user=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        for x in projs:
            if x.restrictions: # restrictions is a string
                split = x.restrictions.split(',')
                for word in split:
                    checking = re.findall("@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+", request.user.username)[0]
                    if word == checking or word == request.user.username:                 
                        break
                    else:
                        projs = projs.exclude(id=x.id)
    else:
        for x in projs:
            if x.restrictions:
                projs = projs.exclude(id=x.id)
```

Comment: "_which I get after running the initial query set in some loops and checking a few conditions and excluding the objects that do not meet the criteria_" what loops and conditions are these? Add them to your question. Django's pagination is as efficient as you would allow it to be. If you allow the query to be completely done by the database it is as efficient as the database allows. If you are doing some operations yourself it is as efficient as you make it.

Comment: hi. thanks for your time. i have added the code for the loops and conditions i am not sure if it will be of any help though.

Comment: As you say the code doesn't make much sense, but from the limited understanding I can get your model schema is not normalized (in simpler words it makes it hard for you to perform queries, introduces difficulties in inserting, updating and deleting entries). For instance `x.restrictions.split(',')` implies comma separated values in one column which violates the 1st normal form itself (each entry in a column should contain only one value). You would find it useful to lookup / research a bit on database normalization.

Comment: right. thanks. i will surely look it up. but say, i was running through the loops and checking 2-3 boolean fields and excluding objects depending on the booleans. then paginate the queryset variable. would it still be efficient? what i mean to ask is.. every time i click on 'next page' will i have to query from the DB or how does it work? I am sorry if this moving away from my initial question.

Comment: A query is made each time you click next page, if you don't do what you do currently and make a queryset normally, then this would use the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses in SQL to get the correct instances. If you say excluding booleans that can be done without loops though? `.exclude(some_attr=False)`, etc. From looking at your code after some normalization you should likely be able to make a single ORM query for this filtering that you want to do.

Comment: you're right. so i should find a way to make single orm query after some normalization. i will try it out. thanks.